# VBCRLF carriage return error in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012, carriage-return

I am using SQL Server 2012 and Visual Studio 2010

I recently upgraded our software which uses SSRS for reporting. All reports were working fine prior to the upgrade. Since the upgrade I now see VBCRLF appearing in the report output. I want to remove this from the output.

Here is how the report design looks in Visual Studio

[image: 1]

Before upgrade (note the headers)

[image: 1]

After the upgrade with VBCRLF problem appearing in the table headers month to date etc..

[image: 1]

Here are the underlying rdl's if they are helpful. This report has a parent and subreport. The charts and table are in the subreport

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/29851290/PortfolioSummary.rdl
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/29851290/PortfolioSummarySubreport.rdl

Any help is appreciated.

***UPDATE

I see in the updated Stored Procedure the company added VBCRLF to indicate carriage returns, but as you see instead of inserting a carriage return, the report shows VBCRLF. Any idea how to tell SSRS when it sees VBCRLF in the code of the underlying sproc to make that a carriage return?

sample code

```
-- Time Period Variables
declare @DTD nvarchar(255) = 'Day VBCRLF To Date'
declare @DTDAnn nvarchar(255) = 'Annualized VBCRLF Day VBCRLF To Date'
declare @ITD nvarchar(255) = 'Inception VBCRLF To Date'
declare @ITDAnn nvarchar(255) = 'Annualized VBCRLF Inception VBCRLF To Date'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do a replace on those header strings with an expression.

Something like:
`=Replace(Fields!MonthToDateHeader.Value,"VBCRLF",vbcrlf)`